# Unable to start Activity ComponentInfo{} java.lang.nullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I'm still in the process of learning java, so I'm sorry if this question is too obvious. I'm trying to launch my app and it throws this error. The problem seems to be in the `OnCreate()` method, but I can't figure out what's causing it.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String NAME = "nick.miros.famous.problems.MESSAGE";
    public final static String EMAIL = "nick.miros.famous.problems.MESSAGE1";
    public final static String STUFFSEX = "nick.miros.famous.problems.MESSAGE2";
    public final static String BIRTHDAY = "nick.miros.famous.problems.MESSAGE3";

    private boolean agreed;
    private String sex;
    public static String bornDate;
    public EditText emailEdit;
    public EditText nameEdit;
    public EditText passwordEdit;
    // public EditText passwordRepeatEdit;
    public RadioGroup radioSex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        emailEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        passwordEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        // passwordRepeatEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRepeat);

        emailEdit.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(emailEdit));
        nameEdit.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(nameEdit));
        passwordEdit
                .addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(passwordEdit));
        // passwordRepeatEdit.addTextChangedListener(new
        // GenericTextWatcher(passwordRepeatEdit));

        Button Go = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
        Go.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sendAndCheck();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private String getSex(int id) {

        switch (id) {

        case R.id.radioMale:
            sex = "Male";
            break;
        case R.id.radioFemale:
            sex = "Female";
            break;
        }
        return sex;
    }

    public void showThanks() {
        Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), R.string.thank_you,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view) {
        // Is the view now checked?
        agreed = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.agreementBox)).isChecked();
    }

    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target)
                    .matches();
        }
    }

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user
            bornDate = Integer.toString(year) + "/" + Integer.toString(month)
                    + "/" + Integer.toString(day);
        }
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendAndCheck() {

        CharSequence emailToCheck = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email))
                .getText().toString();

        if (agreed) {
            // Do something in response to button

            if (isValidEmail(emailToCheck)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
                String sent_name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name))
                        .getText().toString();
                String sent_email = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email))
                        .getText().toString();
                int id = ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioSex))
                        .getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                String sent_sex = getSex(id);
                String sent_birthday = bornDate;
                intent.putExtra(NAME, sent_name);
                intent.putExtra(EMAIL, sent_email);
                intent.putExtra(STUFFSEX, sent_sex);
                intent.putExtra(BIRTHDAY, sent_birthday);
                startActivity(intent);
                showThanks();

            } else {
                ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.email)).setError("wrong email!");
            }

        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder Alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            Alert.setMessage("Please agree with the terms and conditions first");
            Alert.setTitle("Notice");
            Alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            Alert.setCancelable(true);
            Alert.create().show();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the GenericTextWatcher:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{

    private View view;
    private PasswordValidator passwordValidator = new PasswordValidator();
    String password = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
    GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {}

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String text = editable.toString();
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.name:
                if (!(text.equals("")))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ((EditText) view).setError("wrong name!");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.email:
                CharSequence emailToCheck = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
                if (isValidEmail(emailToCheck))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ((EditText) view).setError("wrong email!");

                }

                break;
            case R.id.password:
                if (passwordValidator.isValidPassword(text))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ((EditText) view).setError("must have 1 uppercase letter, 1 number and be 6 characters long");
                }
                break;
           /* case R.id.passwordRepeat:
                String password = (((EditText) view) findViewById(R.id.password).getText().toString();
                if (text.equals(password))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    ((EditText) view).setError("passwords don't match");
                }
                break;*/
        }
    }

    public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target)
                            .matches();
        }
    }

    public class PasswordValidator{

      private Pattern pattern;
      private Matcher matcher;

      private static final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = 
                "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20})";

      public PasswordValidator(){
          pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
      }

      /**
       * Validate password with regular expression
       * @param password password for validation
       * @return true valid password, false invalid password
       */
      public boolean isValidPassword(String password){

          matcher = pattern.matcher(password);
          return matcher.matches();

      }
  }
}
```

Here is the LogCat:

```
02-04 03:59:14.267: D/dalvikvm(2400): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 37K, 7% free 2640K/2820K, paused 1ms, total 34ms
02-04 03:59:14.267: I/dalvikvm-heap(2400): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.319MB for 635808-byte allocation
02-04 03:59:14.277: D/dalvikvm(2400): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3258K/3444K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
02-04 03:59:14.377: D/AndroidRuntime(2400): Shutting down VM
02-04 03:59:14.377: W/dalvikvm(2400): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2eb7648)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nick.miros.famous.problems/nick.miros.famous.problems.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at nick.miros.famous.problems.GenericTextWatcher.<init>(GenericTextWatcher.java:15)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at nick.miros.famous.problems.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-04 03:59:14.377: E/AndroidRuntime(2400):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: please show your logCat

Comment: if it not first activity of your app please post your intent method too where you are launching this activity.

Comment: This is not your full activity code as i can see from your import statement that you also have check-box, radio-group, date-picker and so many other things. So please post full activity code.

Comment: Post GenericTextWatcher line 15

Comment: Are you using custom textwatcher class `new GenericTextWatcher(text)` ? As you did not defined any implementation in your code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `NullPointerException` in `GenericTextWatcher` initialization (`<init>`), on line 15.

In there you have a member variable:

```
String password = ((EditText) view).getText().toString();
```

`view` is `null` at this point, you only assign it in constructor later. Move this code to constructor or later.